# Override Ubuntu 20.04 DNS using systemd-resolved

Tags: ubuntu, dns, systemd-resolved

How do I configure an Ubuntu 20.04 system so it overrides the default DNS?

It seems that by default there is a global and per-link DNS setting.

I tried a couple of things that did not work:

- Edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` with the DNS Servers
- Created `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.conf` with the DNS servers
  configured
- Removed all DNS related parameters from the DHCP request by editing
  `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

All these changes (and the combinations) result in the DNS servers being prepended to the list of global DNS servers.

Most 'solutions' are to either install `resolvconf` or replace the `/etc/resolv.conf` symbolic link with a file and set the DNS servers there. Both of these seem like a workaround.

I would like to use the existing tooling (`systemd-resolved`) to override the DNS Servers.

As suggested by @xenoid in the comments:
Setting the DNS for the interface through the GUI resulted in a file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/enp0s3.nmconnection` that contains the correct DNS servers, the output of `resolvectl status` includes the correct DNS servers, this however is not what I had in mind.
I am looking for a solution that does the configuration using `systemd-resolved`, which is possible from what I can find, but it is unclear how. Since this requires a GUI installation.

Comment: What is your end goal here? Do you want to point the machine to your own DNS server on your local network? Are you on a home network you control or in an enterprise environment?

Comment: I want this system to have different DNS servers from those that are provided over DHCP. While still using the default tooling that is used for configuring DNS.

Comment: *I want this system to have different DNS servers from those that are provided over DHCP* In the network, config dialogs you can configure your system to ignore the DHCP-provided DNS and use specific ones.

Comment: I disable and mask `systemd-resolved` and then hand code the `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to my local `unbound` . You have to delete the resolv.conf link to create a static file.  I have had no problems.

Answer (score 47):

1. Update `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

   ```
   [Resolve]
   DNS=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
   FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4
   ```
2. Restart system resolved: `service systemd-resolved restart`
3. Run `systemd-resolve --status` (or `resolvectl status` in newer versions of systemd). The output should look like this:

   ```
   Global
            DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                         8.8.8.8
   ...
   ```

Comment: I did that, and that did not change the per-link DNS settings

Comment: @SergeFonville Is `systemd-networkd` active? What is the output `networkctl status enp0s3`

Comment: `systemd-networkd` is not active and `networkctl status enp0s3` outputs the settings of the interface, I noticed specifically `State: n/a (unmanaged)`. Do you want to know something specific?

Comment: You need to change the file the `/etc/resolv.conf` link points to. Point it at `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. See this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1774632

Comment: I get "systemd-resolve: command not found"

Comment: Use `resolvectl status` instead. In systemd 239 `systemd-resolve` has been renamed to `resolvectl`.

Answer (score 8):

This [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588658/override-ubuntu-20-04-dns-using-systemd-resolved#comment1170172_588778) from @David R was very helpful:

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -sv /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Why would that work? N.B. that files in `/run` are in memory so *something* has to generate `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` for *something else* to use `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

Let the `iface` variable contain your main interface name, then you can set your DNS addresses this way :

```
$ sudo resolvectl dns $iface x.y.z.t1 x.y.z.t2
$ resolvectl dns $iface
Link 2 (ensX): x.y.z.t1 x.y.z.t2
$ resolvectl status $iface
Link 2 (ensX)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: x.y.z.t1
         DNS Servers: x.y.z.t1
                      x.y.z.t2
          DNS Domain: myDomain.lan
```

Comment: All right (whew) that certainly worked but... will it be made persistent? And, if no, where/what has to be changed to make the change persistent — short of having a script manually setting it up on boot?

Comment: Note: I can confirm that things were changed in `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` but... `/run` is a `tmpfs` in memory... so where does it get stored? Or, rather, where does the non-global configuration come from?

Answer (score 1):

you should explicitly specify in this file `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.conf` to ignore DNS from DHCP. I tend to ignore everything from dhcp in most situations, since I prefer to control this via config-management tools. For example, the DHCPv4 section in the above file would look like:

```
[DHCPv4]
UseHostname=no
UseDNS=no
UseNTP=no
UseDomains=no
```

Also note that you should be using `.network` extension for the file. Also the `[Match]` section can help you so that you dont need to care about what the device name actually is. in my case I dont have any individual device files and instead do overrides when in aws:

```
section of /etc/systemd/network/01-ec2-overrides.network

[Match]
Driver=ena ixgbevf vif

[DHCPv4]
UseHostname=no
UseDNS=no
UseNTP=no
UseDomains=no

[DHCPv6]
UseHostname=no
UseDNS=no
UseNTP=no
```

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong, but first you ask to enter something in `.../enp0s3.conf` and in the next section you ask to use `.network` extension for the file. Do you really mean that same file with just another extension or do you refer to some other file? And then which file are you referring to?