# How to fix Ubuntu GUI after installing windows 11 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows, dual-boot, gui

I recently installed Windows 11 on my second HDD and since then I face issues with Ubuntu improperly loading GUI.

Ubuntu loads to tty1 instead of the graphical user interface (GUI).

`mount -t ext4` returns disk in ro.

I have managed to fix this temporarily.

To address this issue, I have been able to enter a full shell by executing the command `sudo mount / -o remount,rw`. However, after each reboot, the domain resolution breaks and I have been temporarily fixing it by adding the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` using the command `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`.

It solves until next reboot, and then I face the same bugs.

Here is additional information:

```
fedorovn19@fedorovn19-Nitro-AN515-45:~$ sudo fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
[12?q]? 1

*** Filesystem was changed ***
The changes have not yet been written, you can still choose to leave the
filesystem unmodified:
1) Write changes
2) Leave filesystem unchanged
[12?q]? 1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: 201 files, 9450/130812 clusters
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see how installing Windows on the HDD has something to do with GUI on Ubuntu. Are you going through grub? Are you [dropping on a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/q/92556/349837)? About DNS, now [systemd handle it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588778/209677).

Comment: Is the Ubuntu system working correctly when the second HDD containing Windows is removed? If not, it would appear the Windows installation has ate parts of your Ubuntu installation on the first HDD. As fsck says the dirty bit is set, Windows is definitely doing something to the first disk.

Comment: It has been a battle the past couple of days. The whole system went into complete failure message. It stopped after at snap seed.

Comment: I booted into recovery mode -> network then root and somehow it got fixed

Comment: @PavinJoseph I am pathetic, I am afraid something might brake, if i unscrew the hdd.

Comment: @PavelFedotov You're awesome by virtue of being on UNIX :) I would advise checking the RAM/CPU using memtest86 just to cover the bases. Booting from a live ISO, then take an image of the HDD onto an external drive so whatever's the issue it doesn't cause further damage to the data. I have a public guide for setting up Linux Mint Debian Edition with btrfs/snapper that has saved me very recently from my own kernel panic/system crashes due to mismatched memory modules: https://github.com/pavinjosdev/lmde-system-recovery