Unable to access DNS on Linux Mint 20.1
I have a secondary computer that runs as a file server on my local network. I can access it via ssh with no difficulty as it has a fixed IP address.
Problem is through that server, I can't access any DNS.
    $ sudo systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL

My confusion lies in the difference between legacy configuration and systemd configuration. There are multiple solutions to this same problem, but each of them are muddied because of this difference.
I would like some help in a permanent fix to adding an external DNS server to this box.
Thanks

Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588658/100397

Thank you @Chris Davies to help by pointing me to this answer.
I was able to restart the service with a DNS server by adding a line to the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file. On my configuration, this file had commented out the DNS line under the [Resolve] section. Uncommenting this line, and adding the DNS ip address here has fixed the issue.
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844

As a bonus, the DNS seems to persist after a reboot. Thanks.
I still maintain that this is a tricky area to learn because of all the old, outdated answers available when searching.

Please note, with Mint MATE 21.3, 'systemd-resolve' was replaced by   'resolvectl'

See, this is precisely the problem! So many ways to skin this cat.
